# Weird bug with subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

Hey i tried to put the subdivision surface on my obejct and this bug appears

[image]

Someone knows why?

liek this one[image]

Comment: Hello, it doesn't look like a bug, that's the topology that is subdivided by the Subdivision Surface modifier

Comment: You know how to resolve that?

Comment: What shape are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: A smooth one, i tried to move the 2 poins but it stills

Comment: If you want the shading to be smooth you need to right click in Object mode and >Shade Smooth, but topology and shading are 2 different things

Comment: Like the one in the other photo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147843/discussion-between-letz-pro-and-moonboots).

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the reasons why you need to be careful with ngones (polygon with more than 4 sides).

The subdivision modifier basically tries to divide your mesh by two at the tangent position to create each new division.

[image]

The edge at the junction of the slope have geometry "pulling" the generated geometry on each side. But on one side, you have edges departing from its vertices and not from the other, so that created an unbalance and hence the downcurve.

A simple way to fix this would be to add supporting loops parallel to the slope, and continue the edge flow created by the edges of the slope:

[image]